# Deserializing XML to class when the property name is an attribute on each node

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to integrate with a 3rd party REST API. This API always returns all of it's resources as type Asset and it's properties as type Attribute. It uses an attribute on the Attribute nodes to supply the property name. The xml reads as follows:

```
<Assets>
    <Asset>
        <Attribute name="AssetType">Story</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="OwnerName">Fred Blogs</Attribute>
        <Attribute name="Name">The Lord of the Rings</Attribute>
        ...
    </Asset>
    ...
</Assets>
```

I would like to use DataContractSerializer (or XmlSerializer possibly?) to convert this to a list of pocos of type Story.

```
[DataContract(Name="Asset")]
    public class Story
    {
        public string OwnerName { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

The DataMember attribute works on the name of the node, not the value of a nodes attribute as far as I can tell. Is there a way to get round this?

I'd like to end up with a WebAPI client reading as such..

```
    var client = new HttpClient();
    var result = client.GetAsync(uri).Result;
    var stories = r.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Story>>().Result;
```

Comment: That has no direct support in any serializer AFAIK. You may need to deserialize it to a DTO model, then apply the rest manually (maybe some reflection from the name attribute)

Answer (score 1):

How about parsing it with Linq2Xml?

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
var assets = xDoc.Descendants("Asset")
                    .Select(a=>a.Descendants("Attribute")
                                .ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("name").Value, 
                                              x => x.Value))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is the route I'm half way down exploring. Pretty much manual XML parsing but with some LINQ sugar. Hopefully it'll take me all the way.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write a custom serializer to achieve this. See more info here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty01x675(v=vs.80).aspx